# mongoose Model.findOne TypeError: Object has no method 'findOne'

Tags: mongoose

I have a simple node.js code that uses mongoose which works when saving but doesn't retrieve.

`.save()` works, but `.findOne()` doesn't.

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/TestMongoose");
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    field: String
    });
Users = mongoose.model('userauths', UserSchema);

user = new Users({
    field: 'value'
    });

//user.save();
```

^ works. i.e. updates the database with values. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTEvA.png)

---

```
//user.findOne({field:'value'},function(err,value){});
```

^ Throws error:

```
user.findOne({field:'value'},function(err,value){});
     ^
TypeError: Object { field: 'value', _id: 52cd521ea34280f812000001 } has no method 'findOne'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\localhost\nodeTest\z.js:16:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

---

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(   user    , null, 40));
```

^ returns just the object `{field: 'value'}`

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(   Users   , null, 40));
```

^ returns `undefined`

```
Users.findOne();
```

^ no error, but doesn't return anything.
(so does the function `findOne()` exists in `Users`? but so why then does `console.log(..Users..` returns `undefined`?)

What could be the issue causing `findOne()` to not work as expected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`findOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) is a method on your `Users` model, not your `user` model instance.  It provides its async results to the caller via callback:

```
Users.findOne({field:'value'}, function(err, doc) { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the current answer which is correct, notice the difference between userSchema.path and userSchema.statics - the former uses 'this' as the instance of the model, while in the latter 'this' refers to the model "class" itself:

```
       var userSchema = ...mongoose schema...;

       var getUserModel = function () {
            return mongoDB.model('users', userSchema);
        };


       userSchema.path('email').validate(function (value, cb) {
                getUserModel().findOne({email: value}, function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        cb(err);
                    }
                    else if(user){  //we found a user in the DB already, so this email has already been registered
                        cb(null,false);
                    }
                    else{
                        cb(null,true)
                    }
                });
            },'This email address is already taken!');


     userSchema.statics.findByEmailAndPassword = function (email, password, cb) {
                this.findOne({email: email}, function (err, user) {
                    if (err) {
                        return cb(err);
                    }
                    else if (!user) {
                        return cb();
                    }
                    else {
                        bcrypt.compare(password, user.passwordHash, function (err, res) {
                            return cb(err, res ? user : null);
                        });
                    }

                });

            };

        };
```