# User Registration using Mongo and NodeJs not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i have made a usewr registration login in react and node . My signup route is working and user is saved in mongo , but signin route is not working ?

SignIn Component:-

```
signIn(){

axios.post('/tasks/signin', {
  email: this.state.email,
  password: this.state.password,
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Routes are:-

```
Router.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
 var User = new db1();

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email , password: req.body.password 
 }, function(err, user) { 
   console.log(user);  
  if(err) return next(err);
  if(!user) return res.send('Not logged in!');
  return res.send('Logged In!');
  });
});
```

Error:

> User.findOne is not a functionand i am getting 500 status.

Please help  where am i wrong .

Comment: What is db1? Are you using Mongoose or some other framework to connect to Mongo?

Comment: @MarkS. Db1 is model 
const db1 = require('../models/users');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The findOne method is on the model, not the object. So it should be:

```
  db1.findOne({ email: req.body.email , password: req.body.password
```

[See previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20995954/mongooge-model-findone-typeerror-object-has-no-method-findone).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you require the model and assign it to a variable call db1 and create an instance called User. After that, you call the findOne method of the instance instead of the model itself.

If you are using Mongoose, this should be the problem. If not, please give some more details.

Also, it is usually a good practice to call your classes with PascalCase and your instances with camelCase. This way you won't get confused.

Comment: Yes you are right i m a using moongoose and db1 is variable . what shall i do now ?

Comment: Try calling the findOne method of db1 instead of on User.